# How to insert multiple records using single insert statement in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

In teradata, can we insert multiple records using single insert statement in query. If yes, how ?

Say I am trying to do something like:

```
insert test_rank (storeid,prodid,sales) values (1,'A',1000) ( 2,'B',2000) ,(3,'C',3000);
```

but this is not working in teradata to insert all 3 records in one statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO test_rank (storeid, prodid, sales)
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT 0 storeid, 
                   1 prodid, 
                   2 sales) T1 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT 3 storeid, 
                   4 prodid, 
                   5 sales) T2
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT 6 storeid, 
                   7 prodid, 
                   8 sales) T3
      ...
)T;
```

Thanks, Rob! Your advice helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how practical this will be but technically this following is possible:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT *
  FROM 
( SELECT 1 AS StoreID
       , 'A' AS ProdID
       , 1000 AS SALES
  UNION
  SELECT 2 
       , 'B'
       , 2000
  SELECT 3
       , 'C'
       , 3000
) DT1
;
```

Secondly, if you are using BTEQ then you can look into the USING command combined with a flat file repeat single INSERT statement to load the table. But at that point you might as well leverage a proper load utility (MultiLoad or FastLoad) depending on the volumes to accomplish this task if you are doing anything with reasonable volume.

**Edit - 2015-12-10**

The SQL above will not run unless each SELECT in the UNION is first placed in a derived table. See the answer below from Anatoly for the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Yes, no issues with multiple rows insertion if we use BTeQ or loader utilities. In case of MySQL, it works fine if given as-- INSERT INTO TEST_RANK(STOREID,PRODID,SALES)
VALUES (1,'A',1000),(1,'B',2000).....; But I guess Teradata SQL Assistant works in a different way, or may be that's why the loader utilities and BTeQ support are there for. Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessarily SQL Assistant as it is differences in the SQL implementation between MySQL and Teradata.

Comment: @RobPaller - The following doesn't work

`CREATE TABLE MY_DB.MY_TBL (MY_ID VARCHAR(10)) UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX (MY_ID); INSERT INTO MY_DB.MY_TBL 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '0123456789' AS MY_ID UNION SELECT '1234567890') DTA;` I receive a message that "A SELECT for a UNION, INTERSECT, or MINUS must reference a table."

Comment: See the answer below with the derived tables, that bypasses the error in my SQL. Revised my answer to give credit for the correct syntax below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with small data, you can try putting the values inside a text file and import them with the Teradata SQLA.

Create a text file consisting your input, delimited by a tab (use comma if tab doesn't work in your version):

```
1   A   1000
2   B   2000
3   C   3000
```

Then select the import mode on your SQLA, File -> Import Data, and run this following statement:

```
insert into YourTable values (?, ?, ?);
```

Make sure you create the table beforehand, with the correct data types.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is useful to create table **with data** rather than try to make complicated dynamical insert.

```
CREATE TABLE  db.Inc_Config  AS (
SELECT
c.calendar_date,
null  as  Sent_To,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as  Sent_Date,
date '2016-01-01' as  Inc_Start_Date,
date '2016-02-29' as  Inc_End_Date
FROM  sys_calendar.CALENDAR c  
WHERE 
c.calendar_date BETWEEN date '2016-01-01' AND date '2016-02-29' 
) WITH data;
```